# Can't get NSClassFromString working in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I need to instantiate a class from it's class name. I had this working fine in Swift 3, but after converting to Swift 4. I can't make it work any longer. I have tried using `NSClassFromString(_:)` with both `"MyApp.MyClass"` and `"_TtC5MyApp7MyClass"` but without success. And I have also tried using `Bundle.main.classNamed(_:)` function. I even added `@objc(MyBaseClass)`, above the class declaration of `MyClass` to expose it to Objective-C. `MyClass` derives from `MyBaseClass`.

I can't figure out why this isn't working, please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: "I need to instantiate a class from it's class name" That's a Bad Smell. Can you show your use case? Perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: My app reads from a plist a couple of restaurants which all have an id property together with some other information e.g. opening hours. This id refers to a class with the same name which is derived from a Restaurant class. Each of these classes does some web scraping to retrieve the current lunch. I know that it would probably be better to create a web service which does all the heavy lifting, but for now I want to use this solution. Otherwise, I would probably have to pay for a VPS.

Comment: i do the same for one really big list os services and have the same issue :(

Comment: I managed to find the issue, which in my case was an optional that somehow had snucked in and wasn't unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that modulo's name is not the same name of my app.

the diference in my case is that app's name contain "-" and in the Modulo's name It is replace for "_"

Example:
App's name = "My-App"
Modulos name = "My_App"

For that reason  this code don't work

```
let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String
```

For now i put the modulo name hardcode. will improve this answer if i find a better way
You can see your Modulo's name in storybord for example